# How can elements be selected and moved properly?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, interface, edit-mode

I'm having trouble selecting and moving elements in a model.

The recording and file is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kjtZ0u93QXVxScdBTqAmpdYj-EDr5gcm?usp=sharing).

Steps to replicate:

1. Select element (i.e. face)
2. Move outward
3. Move inward
4. Tap on first selected element

Expected:

- When moving outward, faces should not fold.
- When moving inward, form crater.
- When the former face is tapped, it should become selected.

Results:

- When moving outward, faces fold.
- When moving inward, the topology does not dip below the original surface.
- When the former face is tapped again after moving inward, there is no feedback.

I think I might have accidentally ripped everything. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Hi. Please add some images to illustrate the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @RayMairlot here’s a recording https://blender.chat/channel/support?msg=XqP5HKKiNGP53bkPR

Comment: Hi. While videos can be good, ideally all question content should be in the question body, in the form of good descriptions of the issue and images. If that external link goes down at some point (I couldn't actually get it to load) then the question will become unclear (we also want questions to be useful to people who come across them in future and may benefit from any answers you get). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the file, the problem is that you are using a mirror modifier but dint delete half of the mesh, the mesh is mirroring over itself. you can check this by turning off the mirror modifier.

[image: problem with mirror on]
[image]

you have to delete half of the mesh, you can also activate the bisect in the mirror modifier, which an option in the modifier to delete half of the mesh, you can read more on the mirror modifier [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html).

[image: mirror with bisect on]

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the *mirror modifier.* You already have your entire object completely meshed out, but are then mirroring it over on itself. The extra geometry that you are unable to edit is actually the mirrored mesh from the other half.

[image]

You should delete half of the mesh so that the mirror modifier isn't flipping the mesh over onto itself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input.